# My C# table adapter cannot connect with my database MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I have a problem with my table adapter in C#. I cannot connect to my MySQL database, I already tried re-installing MySQL for Visual Studio and the Connector/Net.

The following screenshot shows the MySQL installation on my pc:
[image]

The following screenshot shows the error message I got:
[image]

The following screenshot shows the result of a manual connection test:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem after update the MySQL Connector/NET to newest 8.0.31